# Desired Outputs not coming (Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhQbL.png

Thats the output and my code, i updated the code a little bit but its still showing the same output.

Heres the entire code, btw: http://pastebin.com/QRExvWpa

(If you're wondering what the program is about, we have to check the format of the userid, the first letter should be capital, the next 3 should be lower case, and then the next 3 should be numbers, its not complete yet)

Comment: Do not post link to external site. Code is text, Copy/paste works just fine here

Comment: Please read [Ask] *carefully*.  We need to see code *in* the question, not pictures of code.  We dont need a link to all your code, we need that portion of the code you have determined to be a problem from your extensive debugging efforts.

Comment: Ill keep it in mind next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your input length should be 7 and not 6:
First capital letter, 3 lower ones and finally 3 digits
So , your main "if" clause failed your code always.

From your code:

> If Len(userID) = 6 Then

Following is a sample for the solution.

I could use regular expressions to solve the case in a very simple way (try to read about it yourself!) or write another functions to check if a string is numeric.

But I decided not to and provide a simple solution that you might understand.

I hope you do understand my code.

Feel free to ask for clarifications.

```
Private Function checkUserID(ByVal userid As String) As Boolean

  Dim result As Boolean = False 'this is what the function returns
  Dim i As Integer 'this is a temporary variable for counting during the while-loop
  Dim t As Integer 'this is a temporary boolean flag to decide if should continue the while As Boolean

  userid = userid.Trim()

  If userid.Length = 7 Then

     If ((userid(0) >= "A") And (userid(0) <= "Z")) Then
        i = 1
        t = True

        While (t And (i <= 3))
           If ((userid(i) < "a") Or (userid(i) > "z")) Then
              t = False
           End If
           i = i + 1
        End While

        If t Then

           i = 4
           result = True
           'Since I know this is the last part, I used the final result flag and not the t flag
           'And in the end, the result value is the function value.

           While (result And (i <= 6))
              If ((userid(i) < "0") And (userid(i) > "9")) Then
                 result = False
              End If

              i = i + 1
           End While
        End If
     End If
  End If

  Return result

  End Function
```

How to use:

```
  Dim x1 As String = "Abcd123"
  Dim x2 As String = "A123bcd"
  Dim b As Boolean

  b = checkUserID(x1)
  MsgBox(x1 & "=" + b.ToString)

  b = checkUserID(x2)
  MsgBox(x2 & "=" + b.ToString)
```

Comment: No I do not understand that language.... Im still a student and this was part of a school project. Have to use VB in it

Comment: Sorry, I translated it to VB just for you.
My mistake... 
However, the languages are all similar when it comes to if/else/while/for/case/...Make sure you can read basic code in vb c# or java .